# Send event to event grid from durable function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-eventgrid

How can I send an event to specific event type in event grid topic from durable function activity?

This is my activity function

```
module.exports = async function (context) {
  context.log("Starting StreamingApiActivity...");
  await fetch(webhookURL);
  let dataToReturn = [];

  context.log("activity context: ");
  context.log(context);

  var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

  context.bindings.outputEvent = [];

  context.bindings.outputEvent.push = {
    id: "message-id-1",
    subject: "test-subject",
    dataVersion: "1.0",
    eventType: "test-durable-function-event-type",
    data: "event-data",
    eventTime: timeStamp,
  };
```

And I have configured function.json file as follows

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventGrid",
      "name": "outputEvent",
      "topicEndpointUri": "https://asdf.germanywestcentral-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events",
      "topicKeySetting": "EventGridKey",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

And host.json file

```
{
...
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "notifications": {
        "eventGrid": {
          "topicEndpoint": "https://asdf.germanywestcentral-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events",
          "keySettingName": "EventGridKey"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error which I'm getting

***Unable to resolve the value for property 'EventGridAttribute.TopicEndpointUri'. Make sure the setting exists and has a valid value.***

Comment: Please provide detailed information about what you have tried along with the error screenshot if you are getting any.

Comment: @PravallikaKV Does this added code help you in any way?